# how to use join and like mysql in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
var query = req.params.query;
const messages = await Message.aggregate([

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'reference_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'users'
        }
      },

      {'text': {'$regex': `.*${query}.*`}}
    ])
```

Getting error "message": "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators",

I wanted to join first_name and last_name from users table and search ability based on either first_name, last_name and text how can i achieve this

Comment: Issue occurring in joining collections or search?

Comment: in join it get issue how make it correct, hope you understand my question

Comment: @Shivam : Is `text` also a field in users collection or `message` collection ?

Comment: Yes text is field in message collection

Comment: Just making this question as duplicate as it had answer over there,  [how to work with $lookup and $regex search in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314196/how-to-work-with-lookup-and-regex-search-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because 'text' is not an aggregation pipeline operator.

You can use $text inside of the $match stage.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/ for more details.

I find it's helpful to build a pipeline in an aggregation pipeline builder inside of MongoDB Atlas (cloud.mongodb.com) or using MongoDB Compass (https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) so that you can visually see what's happening at each stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

```
function xyz = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var query = req.params.query;
var aggregate = Message.aggregate();
 aggregate
        .lookup({
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'reference_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'users'
        })
        .match({
           $text: {$search: "$query"}
        )}
         aggregate.exec(function(err, result) {
         if (err) return reject(err);
         return resolve(result);
    });
});
}
```

Make sure your localField id and foreign field id matches.
I hope this help you!