# how to work with $lookup and $regex search in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
  var query = req.params.query;

    const messages = await Message.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'reference_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'users'
        }
      },
      {'text': {'$regex': `.*${query}.*`}}
    ])
```

$lookup is providing me right information but $regex is not properly working When add {'text': {'$regex': `.*${query}.*`}} tells me Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators   after $lookup i have data

```
{
    "response": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "_id": "5e4a8e640b92852e110af62f",
                "text": "Gsshha",
                "reference_id": null,
                "date": 1581944420262,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                        "phone": "1111111111",
                        "first_name": "Test1",
                        "last_name": "Test1",
                        "timestamp": 1581944109860
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e4ce3a4f55dd93292cbe149",
                "unreads": [
                "text": "Hi",
                "reference_id": null,
                "date": 1582097316013,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                        "phone": "1111111111",
                        "first_name": "Test1",
                        "last_name": "Test1",
                        "timestamp": 1581944109860
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve get all the value from `$lookup` and the search string from **text** field, **first_name** field and **last_name** field how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've syntax error in query, Try as like given below :

```
var query = req.params.query;

const messages = await Message.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'reference_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'users'
        }
    }, { $match: { 'text': { '$regex': `.*${query}.*` } } }
])
```

So the issue is when you get this error : **Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators**, As you can see there are certain stages or operators in aggregation like **Ex:-** `$lookup`, `$match`, `$project` etc.. so if aggregate finds anything other it would throw an error. Since you need to filter data you need to wrap you piece of code `'text': { '$regex':`.*${query}.*`}` in `$match`.

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks I tried this way can you please check my answer what's wrong in this ?

Comment: When trying to search it with first name and last name return me blank why ?

Comment: @Shivam : that's because `users` array is created after `$lookup` stage but if you're using `user.first_name` in `$match` prior to `$lookup` query would not be able to find any field named `users`. So it can only work on `text` field but if you use `$match` at last you can query on all 3 fields..